# how to reverse the element of matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to reverse the elements of the matrix such that for given matrix order of the elements get reversed. 
my code is as shown for the 3x3 matrix is working.

```
X  = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9 ];
B = [fliplr(X(3,:));fliplr(X(2,:));fliplr(X(1,:))];
```

input X =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

output:
B =

```
 9     8     7
 6     5     4
 3     2     1
```

the above code I am trying to generalize for any matrix with the following code

```
[a,b]=size(X);
for i=0:a-1
    A  = [fliplr(X(a-i,:))];
end
```

but get only last row as output.

output A =

```
 3     2     1
```

please help me to concatenate all the rows of the matrix one above to each other after it got reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`rot90`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) is the function made for this purpose.

```
B = rot90(A,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you overwrite `A` in every loop iteration. Instead, you should index into A to save each of your rows.

However, `fliplr` can flip a whole matrix. You want to flip left/right and up/down:

```
B = flipud(fliplr(X));
```

This is the same as rotating the matrix (as [Sardar posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50280532/7328782) while I was writing this):

```
B = rot90(X,2);
```

A totally different approach would work for arrays of any dimensionality:

```
X(:) = flipud(X(:));
```

Comment: or `X(end:-1:1) = X(:)`

Comment: @Sardar: True. Or `X(:) = X(end:-1:1)`. :)